# Grabbing .jar application output stream to console after console was closed and new one opened on Oracle Solaris 11

Tags: unix, console, solaris

On Oracle Solaris 11 console when `ps -ef | grep java` command is issued I can see running some java process PID, which was started on other console window and then it (console window) was closed (.jar application output then was visible). Is it some way to grab again that application output without restarting .jar file?

Application was started like this (as a `root` user):

```
java -jar SomeFile.jar &
```

Write output to file is not an option in this case.

Comment: Any reason why you do not follow up with the replies provided so far?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, but it involves some mad skills with **gdb**. Here is how to do that in Linux and I believe you can do the same in Solaris (since it has gdb and it has all needed system calls I'm gonna use further).

There are 3 file descriptors for standard streams:

- stdin: 0
- stdout: 1
- stderr: 2

You are interested in stdout and stderr (both are console output), so you need file descriptors with numbers **1** and **2**, just keep it in mind.

Now I'm gonna show you how to do what you ask for "okular" application (instead of your "java" application) for **stderr** stream.

1. Run "okular" in terminal, like this:

   ```
   $ okular &
   ```

   and then close this terminal. This is just to simulate your situation.
2. Open another terminal
3. Look for "okular" process:

   ```
   $ ps aux | grep okular
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   joe      27599  2.2  0.9 515644 73944 ?        S    23:46   0:00 okular
   ```

   So "okular" PID is **27599**.
4. Look for open file descriptors of "okular" process:

   ```
   $ ls -l /proc/27599/fd
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   lrwx------ 1 joe joe 64 Feb 18 23:46 0 -> /dev/pts/0 (deleted)
   lrwx------ 1 joe joe 64 Feb 18 23:46 1 -> /dev/pts/0 (deleted)
   lrwx------ 1 joe joe 64 Feb 18 23:46 2 -> /dev/pts/0 (deleted)
   ```

   You see that all 3 streams are deleted.
5. Now let's attach to our process with **gdb**:

   ```
   $ gdb -p 27599 /usr/bin/okular
   ```

   Inside of gdb perform next operations:

   ```
   (gdb) p close(2)
   (gdb) p creat("/tmp/okular_2", 0600)
   (gdb) detach
   (gdb) quit
   ```

   Here we invoked 2 system calls:

   - **close()**, to close file for **stderr** stream of our process
   - **creat()**, to create new file for **stderr** stream of our process

   **p** is gdb command, it prints (in our case) system calls return values.
6. Now all new **stderr** output of our process will be appended to text file **/tmp/okular_2**. We can read it constantly this way:

   ```
   $ tail -f /tmp/okular_2
   ```

### Conclusion

Ok, that's it, we revived **stderr** stream. You can do the same for **stdout** stream, the only difference is that you need to call "close(1)" instead of "close(2)" in gdb. Also, in your case be sure to replace all "okular" words with your "java" word.

The most of answer was inspired by [this article](http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/).

If you need to revive **stdin** stream, you can attach it to pipe (FIFO) file, see details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process).

Comment: Trying to find `gdm` on Solaris11. I think I need to install this package first.

Comment: Only it's **gdb**, not **gdm** :) Yes, you can install it from here (for Solaris): http://sunfreeware.com . Or you can build it manually: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/installing_gdb.htm .

Actually you can use any debugger, not only gdb. Just be sure that it's able to attach to process and perform system calls. Syntax may vary though, so I recommend you to use gdb, because I've tested the procedure I provided (using gdb) and it works.

Comment: I've tried like this: `gdb -p 3228 someApp.jar`, but among some results I found this line: `"someApp.jar": not in executable format: File format not recognized`.. Very strange..

Comment: You can use just "gdb -p 3228". If you want to provide executable binary to gdb (for symbols), you should provide path to "java" executable, not to your jar file.

Comment: OK, so now I got this output: `Attaching to process 3228
Retry #1:
Retry #2:
Retry #3:
Retry #4:
[New LWP 1]
0xff27bf0a in ?? ()
(gdb)`. Seems not very useful information.. (total 8 lines - hard to format here in comments :) Of course - PID 3228 is just for example.

Comment: But you end up in GDB shell and you are able to execute commands, right? Or it just hangs?

Comment: This application do not accepts any commands (not uses `InputStream` like `System.in`), just does an output. But I can try soon to implement it for testing. Terminal do not hangs up, everything works fine.

Comment: Why did you mention input stream? As I understood from initial question, you only need the output from this application. You don't need to implement input stream for this. And if your terminal (and GDB) doesn't hang up, you should be able to perform GDB commands (see my initial answer) and finally get the output stream from your java application. Have you managed to do that or something still doesn't work?

Comment: When I issue command inside GDB - `p close(2)` - I'm getting the error: `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`. And this command `ls -l /proc/27599/fd` do not show like `lrwx------ 1 joe joe 64 Feb 18 23:46 0 -> /dev/pts/0 (deleted)` as you mentioned, but among other lines I can also see `c---------   1 someuser    tty      221,  1 Feb 20 11:07 0`.. but nothing like `/dev/pts/0 (deleted)`..

Comment: To pass symbol table to GDB, you first need to figure out where is your "java" binary resides: `which java`. It will give you something like `/usr/bin/java`. Then provide this "java" binary to gdb, like this: `gdb -p 27599 /usr/bin/java`. Regarding **/proc** output -- I think it shouldn't affect you, but please provide full output of `ls -l /proc/27599/fd` command (you can share it using [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) service).

Comment: I found that I can use use `screen` very easy. Steps: 1) `screen`; 2) launching .jar file; 3) connection is lost, new terminal started; 4) `screen -x` - and the output appears again :) Very easy. To detach from `screen` - CTRL+A+D. Thanks indeed for help @Sam Protsenko. You can try yourself to launch `.jar` file on your system if you have a time, it would be very nice to know the results with `GDB`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to snoop any process output with Solaris native tools.

One way would be using `dtrace` which allows tracing processes even when they are already grabbed by a debugger or similar tool.

This `dtrace` script will display a given process `stdout`:

```
#!/bin/ksh
pid=$1
dtrace -qn "syscall::write:entry /pid == $pid && arg0 == 1 /
  { printf(\"%s\",copyinstr(arg1)); }"
```

You should should pass the process id of the java application to trace as its first argument, eg. `$(pgrep -f "java -jar SomeFile.jar")`.

Replace `arg0 == 1` by `arg0 == 2` if you want to trace `stderr` vs `stdin`.

Should you want to see non displayable characters (in octal), you might use this slightly modified version:

```
#!/bin/ksh
pid=$1
dtrace -qn "syscall::write:entry /pid == $pid && arg0 == 1 /
  { printf(\"%s\",copyinstr(arg1)); }" | od -c
```

Another native way is to use the `truss` command. The following script will show all writes from your process to any file descriptors, and will include a full detailed trace for both `stdout` and `stderr` (3799 is your target process pid):

```
truss -w1,2 -t write -p 3799
```

---

dtrace:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5488/gcgkk.html

truss:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/truss-1.html#scrolltoc

Comment: I got this error: `dtrace: invalid probe specifier syscall::write:entry /3799 ==  && arg0 == 1 /  { printf(%s,copyinstr(arg1)); }: syntax error near "&&"`

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. This script expected a shell variable named pid to contain the process id of the program to trace. There was another issue with double quotes. Reply edited with a tested way.

Comment: Yes, it's working, but I see lot's of errors in text output. Looks like white squares in terminal window...

Comment: What makes you assert these are errors? These squares might just be non ASCII characters either the JVM or your terminal emulator is unable to represent. You can pipe the script output to `od -c` to see the octal value of them. Reply updated again with an alternate way that will also help figuring out what these characters precisely are.